# Using a variable to fetch the username and it breaks in two

Tags: regex, perl, sqlmap

I'm writing a program which will use [`sqlmap`](http://sqlmap.org/) to do a simple scan and then use regex patterns to look for *critical* errors in my database.

The problem is that I am storing the output of `sqlmap` in a text file. If I put that file in the root directory it's fine, but if I try to store it under the logged-in user's home directory then I get this error

> ```
> sh1: cannot creat /home/user
> sh2: /Desktop/results.txt not found
> ```

Here is the code that is causing this error

```
$u = `id -u -n`;
my $com = `sqlmap -m $ARGV[0] >> /home/$u/Desktop/results.txt --batch`;
```

I don't understand why the variable `$u` is breaking the path `/home/$u/Desktop/results.txt` into two separate strings.

Comment: looks like there's a newline, try running $u through chomp

Comment: You are correct. A question if you don't mind: every time we run batch commands via PERL we get a command with a newline? Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: No, only if the command outputs the newline.

Comment: `~/Desktop/results.txt`?

Answer (score 7):

Perl has a function to get the username, no need to call an external command:

```
my $u = getpwuid $<;
```

Note that nothing guarantees the user's home will be in `/home/$u` (cf. the root's home: `/root`). [File::HomeDir](http://p3rl.org/File::HomeDir) can help you. Or, use `~/` for the shell command.

Comment: What is the difference between using a function or calling a batch to do it for us? I'm looking for a technical point of view since i know the difference between the two in practice.

Comment: @BrunoFrancisco: The function is usually faster, the code is cleaner, and you don't run into issues with newlines in unexpected places.

Comment: Thank you for your time sir.